# jquery data returns "undefined is not a function" when the data value is a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, integer, undefined

I just discovered that if the value of a `data()` is a number, I get "undefined is not a function" when trying to call it. I'm doing:

```
$path = $('td#folder-'+sfx+' a').data('name');
```

Then throwing $path into the data of an ajax request like

```
 path : $path,
```

When the value of `data('name')` is any integer (1, 2, 2335343, whatever), I get "undefined is not a function." If I rename the value to a string (e.g., `9ER`), I have no problems.

Why is this and what can I do about it?

**UPDATED**

As requested, here's the bulk of the code:

```
             $(proceed).on('click', function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    proceed.fadeOut(500);
                    canceldel.fadeOut(500);
                    confirms.fadeOut(500);                  
                    rename.fadeIn(1000);
                    del.fadeIn(1000);       
                    $subdir = $('td#folder-'+sfx+' a').data('name');
                    $path1 = $bm;
                    $path2 = $subdir;
                    if($path1.indexOf('..') >= 0 || $path1 === '/' || $path1 === '' || !$path1 || $path1 === 'undefined' || $path1 === undefined){
                        filertify.set({labels:{ok : "OK" }}); filertify.alert('There was an error completing your request. The path to the directory has not been properly defined.');
                    }else if($path2.indexOf('..') >= 0 || $path2 === '/' || $path2 === '' || !$path2 || $path2 === 'undefined' || $path2 === undefined){
                        filertify.set({labels:{ok : "OK" }}); filertify.alert('There was an error completing your request. The path to the directory has not been properly defined.');
                    }else{
                        $.post(
                            SSFA_FM_Ajax.ajaxurl,
                            {
                                action : 'ajax-ssfa-file-manager',
                                dataType : 'html',  
                                act : 'deletedir',
                                status : 'life',
                                path1 : $path1,
                                path2 : $path2,
                                nextNonce : SSFA_FM_Ajax.nextNonce
                            },
                            function(response){
```

etc.

If I call it as `$(element).attr('data-name')` I don't get the error, but I want the `data()` version.

Comment: I tried $path.toString(); but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle where this behaviour occurs?

Comment: Yeah, give me a sec. See if I can duplicate it.

Comment: So far I can't duplicate the problem in the fiddle. I'll keep trying, but I can't really go as far as the ajax request in the fiddle.

Comment: What does the entire ajax-call look like?

Comment: Actually it might be occurring in a check I do on the value right before the ajax call. I'll add it to the thing above. If I call it as an attribute I don't get the problem either, but I want the cached version of course.

Comment: If you log both outputs (`$(element).attr('data-name')` and `$(element).data('name')`) to the console, are there any differences?

Comment: No difference in the console. Both output 1

Comment: Definitely found out the error is triggered by my security checks before the ajax call. I took out the $path2 checks and it goes through.

Comment: The culprit seems to be this check: `if($path2.indexOf('..') >= 0)` but only if the value of $path2 is an integer.

Comment: And apparently that's why. indexOf doesn't like integers, which makes sense.

Comment: `indexOf()` isn't a function of an integer, hence the undefined warning. Perhaps you should first check if the variable is indeed an integer or a string.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. This is good to know. Of course, I wasn't counting on encountering integers as directory names, but now I know what to do. Thanks much!

Comment: No problem! Glad we could work to a solution :)